# Trying to download image but server is not sending data

Tags: c#, wget

I am trying to download this image using C#

http://www.pinkice.com/data/product_image/1/13954Untitled-1.jpg

When I try to download it using a WebClient I get an exception saying the underlying connection was closed unexpectedly.

I've tried modifying the headers to simulate chrome

```
Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";
Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "max-age=0";
Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1243.2 Safari/537.6";
```

This did not work. I then tried to see if it even worked with wget

```
wget "http://www.pinkice.com/data/product_image/1/14231Untitled-2.jpg"
```

Which resulted in

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received. Retrying.
```

Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: this can happen even due to proxy, so first tell us the exceptional things about your environment

Comment: There's nothing special about my environment. Just running it from a home network, I can see it on Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using reusing the WebClient object. I think it caches something weirdly when there is a 304 HTTP Status code from the  If-Modified-Since header.  Moral of the story is do not try to reuse the WebClient object.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works..

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{

    wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1";
    byte[] buf = wc.DownloadData("http://www.pinkice.com/data/product_image/1/13954Untitled-1.jpg");
    Image bmp = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buf));
}
```

Comment: @SwearWord Above code works, I tested it. Have you tried it with `wc.Proxy=null` ?

Comment: Yes I have, I think I need to test it on another network and see if it's something bizarre with mine.